# struts2 Using the date tag

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2

I am using the date tag as follows:

```
<s:date name="datePosted"   nice="true" />
```

If the date was set at 2012-11-21 13:03:20, it is showing up as 13 hours, 25 minutes ago.
I need it to compare the current time and show the difference between them. Like 2 minutes 30 seconds ago.

Comment: what is your question again? if you set it with `nice`, it shows exactly what you want.

Comment: I have set it to 'nice'. However it uses the hour as 13 and the minutes as 25 directly. I wanted it to show the difference from the current time. Like 2 minutes ago.

Comment: What is the relation with the i18n key? [https://struts.apache.org/2.0.6/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/components/Date.html]

Comment: i18n keys works, if you want to show your date in aonther language

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. It was my mistake at the back end. 
The date that I was retrieving from was actually from a mysql Timestamp field. 
I was using `recordSet.getDate()` instead of `recordSet.getTimestamp()`.
My solution was to use something like:

```
Date datePosted=new Date(rs.getTimestamp().getTime());
```

This copies the time(long) value from the Timestamp Object to the Date object.